# Use PHPmailer or regualer PHP mail to send text: From $Phone-Number

Tags: php, phpmailer

Can I send a text message using PHP or PHPmailer and in the return use a phone number and not an email?

PHP mail() and PHPmailer makes me use a valid email with an "@" symbol. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can put whatever you want in the from field, but don't expect your mail server, or the receiving mail server to accept it.

Better to set your `from:` field to something like this instead:

```
"123-123-1234 <noreply@yourdomain.com>"
```

That way, you can have a valid from address, and still display a number to the end user.

Comment: Thank you. This works when sending to an email but if you send it to a phone it doesn't work. But thank you so far! 

DOESN'T WORK TO CELL PHONE:
<?php
$to = "701######@vtext.com";
$subject = "";
$message = "HELLO THIS IS A TEXT";
$from = "701-#######<noreply@none.com>";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>

Comment: @user894237, It depends on the e-mail client, which in your case is actually an e-mail to SMS gateway.  There is nothing you can do about that.  If you want to send SMS messages, you're better off actually sending SMS messages via a gateway.